# Why is Mathematica not simplifying further even after providing assumptions?

Tags: differential-equations, eigenvalues

```
m = {{0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {-5 X^2, X^2, 0, 0}, {X^2, -X^2, 0, 0}};
Simplify[Eigenvalues[m], Assumptions -> X>0]
```

The output I get is this below. The last two eigenvalues are not in their simplest form. They too are complex numbers.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a simple way:

```
   Simplify[Eigenvalues[m], Assumptions -> X > 0] // PowerExpand
```

I think the function `ComplexityFunction` or function `TransformationFunctions` is likely to do the same, but I don't know how to do it yet.

Comment: Shorter: `Simplify[Eigenvalues[m], X > 0] // PowerExpand`

Comment: Not the shortest, but there is a Wolfram Function Repository that can be of use once the eigenvalues are properly preprocessed: `Map[ResourceFunction["RadicalDenest"], PowerExpand[Factor[evals]]]`